# SQL Rows in updated in last 10 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure is something like below:

`Table: Employee`

```
<br><br>
<pre>
  <tr>
    <td>EName</td>
    <td>EId</td>
    <td>DeptNo</td>
    <td>DOJ</td>
  </tr>
  <br>
  <tr>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>12/9/2013 2:47:35 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <br>
  <tr>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>12/9/2013 2:47:35 PM</td>
  </tr>
  <br>
  <tr>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>12/9/2013 8:25:45 AM</td>
  </tr>
  <br>
  <tr>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>-</td>
  </tr>
  <br>
</pre>
.... 
<br>
```

I need to fetch the employee Name who joined in last 10 hours... how do I do it?

Comment: Please use the search function on SO.

Comment: can you give me an example .. how to use it?

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM TABLE

Comment: nice edit!! first it was unclear now it got even worse !!

Comment: last_insert_id() function wont' work.

Answer (score 0):

Might this will work

```
SELECT ENAME FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE 
HOUR(TIMEDIFF(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 HOUR),NOW())) <= 10
```